# Powershell - compare files and content

Tags: powershell

I need to compare the content of files on 2 different machines. There are around 50 files in the folder on each PC. So far I have done this:

```
compare (gc \\PC1\d$\Data\Config\*) (gc \\PC2\d$\Data\Config\*) | Out-GridView
```

and it works fine, but in that way I can't see in which file the difference exist. So I need the filename in the result.

Comment: `gc \\PC1\d$\Data\Config\*` returns _unstructured_ array of lines from all files in `\\PC1\d$\Data\Config` folder; the same holds for  `gc \\PC2\d$\Data\Config\*`. Therefore you can't grab filenames. You need to compare individually, file by file taken from `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

If files under folder "...\Config" are same .
You may need to compare with each file :

Edited:

```
Get-ChildItem \\PC1\d$\Data\Config\* | %{$path1 = "\\PC1\d$\Data\Config\$($_.name)" ;$path2 = "\\PC2\d$\Data\Config\$($_.name)" ; $dif = compare (gc $path1) (gc $path2);if ($dif) {$_.name;$dif}}
```

Comment: Files should be the same, because these Point-Of-Sale PC's are made from the same image, but the content of the files is not totally the same. But this doesn't seem to work. I have replaced \\PC1\..... with the original destination. I get this error: Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:106

Comment: I have edited the commands .
Please test it again .

Comment: Well I can see in which files the difference is, and I can see the difference, but I still have a lot this: Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:261
+ ... $dif = compare (gc $path1) (gc $path2);if ($dif) {$_.name;$dif}}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand

Comment: By the way I have added "-Exclude data" because it's folder with limited access to and it will fail everytime, but it's not important.